# How to create a Gallery which images get bigger in the middle

Tags: javascript, css

I want to create a gallery which the images get bigger in the middle.
[image]
The ammont of images are random.

With this `code`, I could find the middle, but I dont know how to change the `size` of the `Images` ascendens and/or descendant.

```js
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
var middle = boxes[Math.round((boxes.length - 1) / 2)];
middle.style.width = "70px"
middle.style.height= "70px"
```

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
.box{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:black;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as the other answer except the size calculation is moved to CSS

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
let middle = Math.floor((boxes.length - 1) / 2);

const reductionModifier = 4; //Reduces size diff, higher means less diff.
const marginModifier = -1; //-1 means margin will be -10px

boxes.forEach((e, i) => {
    e.style.setProperty('--s',  1 - ((Math.abs(i - middle) / boxes.length) / reductionModifier));
    e.style.setProperty('--m', i == middle ? 1 : marginModifier);
    e.style.setProperty('--z',  1 - Math.abs(i - middle));
});
```

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: calc(70px * var(--s));
  height: calc(70px * var(--s));
  background-color:black;
  margin: calc(10px * var(--m));
  z-index: calc(10 * var(--z));
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to give them a nigative margin, so could you add also an Index for each of them, so the middle ones get infront of the rest Items?

Comment: Something like this?

Comment: How can I reduce the size of the differences between the boxes?

Comment: I added a `reductionModifier` const, the higher it is, the less is the difference between boxes. Word of caution though, the `z-index` may break a bit if the diff becomes too small.

Comment: It would be great if the **reductionModifier** == 4 and nothing breaks :)

Comment: Getting picky are we, added additional CSS variables to control them independently.

Answer (score 2):

something like this.. you can play with the number, depending on how much bigger or smaller you want them..

```js
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
var middle_index = Math.round((boxes.length - 1) / 2);
for ( var i=0; i<boxes.length; i++) {
boxes[i].style.width =  `${70-Math.abs(boxes.length-i*2-1)*5}px`;
boxes[i].style.height = `${70-Math.abs(boxes.length-i*2-1)*5}px`;
}
```

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
.box{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:black;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It wont work when I have 3 Items :/

Comment: And also when I have more than 3 Items and they are odd :/

Comment: i modified the answer..

Comment: Thank you, but it wont work yet if the Items are more than 4 and are odd.

Comment: if you run the code snippet, there are  5 items there, for me it seems fine..

Comment: I meant even, sorry